# R: condition over each $

Tags: r

I need to find the number of "P"s in each team($ANA, $ARI, etc) from the data below. I thought of using subset() but I don't know what to put into the condition. Can anyone suggest a way of doing it?

```
$ANA  
[1] P  RF LF P  P   
Levels: 1B 2B 3B C CF LF P RF SS

$ARI  
[1] P  P  1B 3B P   
Levels: 1B 2B 3B C CF LF P RF SS

$ATL  
[1] P  C  3B P  P   
Levels: 1B 2B 3B C CF LF P RF SS

$BAL  
[1] P  3B P  SS P   
Levels: 1B 2B 3B C CF LF P RF SS
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is a 'list', then try

```
 vapply(lst, function(x) sum(x=='P'), 0) 
 #   ANA ARI ATL BAL 
 #    3   3   3   3
```

Or

```
 vapply(lst, function(x) table(x)[7],0) 
 #ANA ARI ATL BAL 
 # 3   3   3   3
```

Or

```
  colSums(mapply(`==`, lst, 'P'))
  #ANA ARI ATL BAL 
  # 3   3   3   3
```

#### data

```
lvls <-  c('1B', '2B', '3B', 'C', 'CF', 'LF', 'P', 'RF', 'SS')

lst <- list(ANA= factor(c('P', 'RF', 'LF', 'P', 'P'), levels=lvls),
ARI=factor(c('P', 'P', '1B', '3B', 'P'), levels=lvls), 
ATL=factor(c('P', 'C', '3B', 'P', 'P'), levels=lvls), 
BAL=factor(c('P', '3B', 'P', 'SS', 'P'), levels=lvls))
```